# Turtle command name not found

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm having trouble getting function calls to work. Here is a sample call:

```
def polyline(t,n,length,angle):
    """Draws n line segments with the given length and 
    angle(in degrees) between them. t is a turtle.
    """
    for i in range(n):
        t.fd(length)
        t.lt(angle)
```

The associated call goes like

```
alex=turtle.Turtle()

polyline(alex,5,100,90)
```

I've already imported turtle but I get the following error:

```
TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I have to continously define alex just before I make the function call. For instance this worked:

```
 def polyline(t,n,length,angle):
    """Draws n line segments with the given length and 
    angle(in degrees) between them. t is a turtle.
    """
    for i in range(n):
        t.fd(length)
        t.lt(angle)


alex=turtle.Turtle() 
#Test polyline
polyline(alex,5,780,90)
```

This fails:

```
alex=turtle.Turtle() 
#insert some other functions


 #define polyline function

#call polyline
```